Is there a common name for a data structure for one or multiple consumers receiving most recent data from a single producer?
The behavior is very simple:

N slots are needed, where N is the number of consumers plus 2.
The producer locks a slot for writing, which is not locked by a consumer and is not the last written
Some time later the producer unlocks that slot and marks it as the last written
A consumer locks the last written slot for reading (increments the lock count)
Some time later consumer decrements the lock count

In case of one producer and one consumer it is called "Triple buffering" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering
and one simple implementation was posted here How to correctly implement triple buffering?
However, all discussion of Triple buffering always focus on video buffers, graphics hardware, displays, fps, etc. and they do not discuss multiple consumers.
But I would like to use the same idea for other purposes, for example to post most recent settings or status structures from one thread to others.
Is there a common name for such structure? If not in computer science, then, may be, in some popular library?

There is another and much simpler approach to this problem.
The Ada programming language provides the ability to define what Ada calls "protected objects". These objects are implicitly protected from race conditions. The following Ada producer-consumer example works for any number of producers and consumers without adjusting slots.
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is
   type Idx_T is mod 10;
   type Circular_Buffer is array (Idx_T) of Integer;

   protected Buffer is
      entry Enqueue (Value : in Integer);
      entry Dequeue (Value : out Integer);
   private
      Cb        : Circular_Buffer;
      Write_Idx : Idx_T   := 0;
      Read_Idx  : Idx_T   := 0;
      Count     : Natural := 0;
   end Buffer;

   protected body Buffer is
      entry Enqueue (Value : in Integer) when Count < Cb'Length is
      begin
         Cb (Write_Idx) := Value;
         Write_Idx      := Write_Idx + 1;
         Count          := Count + 1;
      end Enqueue;

      entry Dequeue (Value : out Integer) when Count > 0 is
      begin
         Value    := Cb (Read_Idx);
         Read_Idx := Read_Idx + 1;
         Count    := Count - 1;
      end Dequeue;
   end Buffer;

   task type Producer is
      entry Set_Id (Num : Positive);
      entry Stop;
   end Producer;

   task type Consumer is
      entry Set_Id (Num : Positive);
      entry Stop;
   end Consumer;

   task body Producer is
      My_Id : Positive;
      I     : Positive := 1;
   begin
      accept Set_Id (Num : Positive) do
         My_Id := Num;
      end Set_Id;
      loop
         select
            accept Stop;
            exit;
         else
            select
               Buffer.Enqueue (I);
               Put_Line ("Producer" & My_Id'Image & " produced" & I'Image);
               I := I + 1;
               delay 0.001;
            or
               delay 0.001;
            end select;
         end select;
      end loop;
      Put_Line ("Producer" & My_Id'Image & " stopped.");
   end Producer;

   task body Consumer is
      My_Id  : Positive;
      My_Num : Positive;
   begin
      accept Set_Id (Num : Positive) do
         My_Id := Num;
      end Set_Id;
      loop
         select
            accept Stop;
            exit;
         else
            select
               Buffer.Dequeue (My_Num);
               Put_Line
                 ("    Consumer" & My_Id'Image & " consumed" & My_Num'Image);
               delay 0.001;
            or
               delay 0.001;
            end select;
         end select;
      end loop;
      Put_Line ("Consumer" & My_Id'Image & " stopped.");
   end Consumer;

   P1 : Producer;
   P2 : Producer;
   C1 : Consumer;
   C2 : Consumer;
   C3 : Consumer;
begin
   P1.Set_Id (1);
   P2.Set_Id (2);
   C1.Set_Id (1);
   C2.Set_Id (2);
   C3.Set_Id (3);

   delay 0.1;
   P1.Stop;
   P2.Stop;
   C1.Stop;
   C2.Stop;
   C3.Stop;

end Main;

Ada protected objects are defined in two steps. The first step is the specification of the protected object, containing a declaration of the public methods defined for the protected object and a private declaration of the data members of the protected object. A protected object allows three kinds of methods to be declared. Procedures execute unconditionally and maintain an exclusive read-write lock on the protected object. Entries execute conditionally, based upon the evaluation of their boundary condition. Entries maintain an exclusive read-write lock on the protected object. Functions are only allowed to read the state of the protected object. Functions maintain a shared read lock on the protected object.
This example only declares two entries named Enqueue and Dequeue. Enqueue writes an integer value to the protected object. Dequeue reads an integer value from the protected object.
The implementation of the methods declared in the protected specification are found in the protected body. The Enqueue entry has a boundary condition specified as:
when Count < Cb'Length

This means the Enqueue entry can operate only when Count is less than the number of elements in the array Cb. In other words, Enqueue can only execute when the buffer is not full.
The Dequeue entry has a boundary condition expressed as:
when Count > 0

This logic prevents the Dequeue entry from executing when the Buffer is empty.
Two task types are defined. The Producer task type writes values to the Buffer protected object until its Stop entry is called. The Consumer task type reads values from the Buffer protected object until its Stop entry is called.
This example creates two instances of the Producer task type named P1 and P2. It also creates three instances of the Consumer task type named C1, C2, and C3.
An example output of this program is:
Producer 1 produced 1
Producer 2 produced 1
    Consumer 1 consumed 1
    Consumer 2 consumed 1
Producer 1 produced 2
    Consumer 3 consumed 2
    Consumer 1 consumed 2
Producer 2 produced 2
Producer 1 produced 3
    Consumer 2 consumed 3
Producer 2 produced 3
    Consumer 3 consumed 3
Producer 2 produced 4
    Consumer 1 consumed 4
Producer 1 produced 4
    Consumer 2 consumed 4
Producer 2 produced 5
    Consumer 3 consumed 5
Producer 1 produced 5
    Consumer 2 consumed 5
Producer 1 produced 6
    Consumer 3 consumed 6
Producer 2 produced 6
    Consumer 1 consumed 6
Producer 1 produced 7
Producer 2 produced 7
    Consumer 3 consumed 7
    Consumer 2 consumed 7
Producer 2 produced 8
    Consumer 3 consumed 8
    Consumer 1 consumed 8
Producer 1 produced 8
Producer 1 produced 9
    Consumer 2 consumed 9
Producer 2 produced 9
    Consumer 3 consumed 9
Producer 1 stopped.
Producer 2 produced 10
    Consumer 3 consumed 10
Producer 2 stopped.
Consumer 1 stopped.
Consumer 2 stopped.
Consumer 3 stopped.

EDIT:
Here is a solution with no locking. Perhaps this is more like what you want. The intention here is to implement page swapping using two array elements. Each array element contains one full buffer for writing and/or reading.
This example uses direct synchronous communication between the producer task and the display task. No object locking occurs.
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Buffered_Tasks is
   Empty_Buffer : constant Integer := Integer'First;
   
   type Idx_T is mod 2;
   
   type Buff_Arr is array (Idx_T) of Integer
     with Default_Component_Value => Empty_Buffer;
   
   Buffers : Buff_Arr;
   
   task display is
      entry Stop;
      entry Read(Idx : Idx_t);
   end display;
   
   task body display is
      Read_Idx : Idx_T;
   begin
      loop
         select
            accept stop;
            Put_Line("Display stopping");
            exit;
         else
            select
               accept Read(Idx : Idx_T) do
                  Read_Idx := Idx;
               end Read;
               Put_Line ("Display read " & Buffers(Read_Idx)'Image);
            or
               Delay 0.001;
            end select;
         end select;
      end loop;
   end display;
   
   Write_Idx : Idx_T := 0;
   
begin
   for I in 1 .. 10 loop
      Buffers(Write_Idx) := I;
      Put_Line("Producer wrote " & I'Image);
      Display.Read(Write_Idx);
      Write_Idx := Write_Idx + 1;
   end loop;
   Display.Stop;
end Buffered_Tasks;

The display polls for an event notification from the producer that the buffer is ready to read. The producer writes to the buffer, sends an event to the display task indicating which array element to read, increments the array element index and repeats the process.
The array index increment operation works correctly because the array index type is defined as a modular type with two values: 0 and 1. Incrementing the value 1 results in 0 in this example.
The output of this example is:
Producer wrote  1
Display read  1
Producer wrote  2
Display read  2
Producer wrote  3
Display read  3
Producer wrote  4
Display read  4
Producer wrote  5
Display read  5
Producer wrote  6
Display read  6
Producer wrote  7
Display read  7
Producer wrote  8
Display read  8
Producer wrote  9
Display read  9
Producer wrote  10
Display read  10
Display stopping


I tried to read about Ada "Protected Objects" in https://learn.adacore.com/courses/intro-to-ada/chapters/tasking.html#protected-objects and https://blog.adacore.com/priority-extending-mutexes but still cannot figure out: is "Protected Object" the same as "mutex" in any other language or is it lock-free? The purpose of "Triple Buffer" or other modern lock-free algorithms is to avoid using expensive mutexes. Suppose one consumer needs to write the object to a file, which may take a second or more. Clearly, doing it under a mutex is a show stopper.

@jhnlmn Your description of the "Triple Buffer" does not sound lock-free to me:
2. The producer locks a slot for writing, which is not locked by a consumer and is not the last written
3. Some time later the producer unlocks that slot and marks it as the last written
4. A consumer locks the last written slot for reading (increments the lock count).
This is what is done using the protected object. I see no performance advantages in your description.

I should have used term "block free" rather than "lock free". It is true that buffers are atomically locked and unlocked, but under no circumstances producer or consumers can block waiting for each other, like it happens with a mutex. And it appears that "Protected Objects" in Ada also have mutex inside, does it? Unfortunately, I do not know Ada and do not understand your code. in Particular, what happens if Producer keep object locked, but Consumer needs to read? Or vice versa?

In Ada neither the Producer nor the Consumer control the locking. The protected object controls its own internal state, and locking is part of its internal state. Consider the protected object an implementation of Object Oriented Programming, where each object controls its own state. In my example the Producer calls the Enqueue entry, which only locks the protected object while the Enqueue entry is executing. Similarly, the Consumer calls the Dequeue entry, which only locks the protected object while the entry is executing.

The Producer and Consumer merely call their respective entries in the protected object. There is no way for the programmer or the calling task to confuse locking and unlocking sequences. Furthermore, the entry boundary conditions prevent the Producer from writing to the protected object when its internal buffer is full and also prevent the Consumer from reading from the protected object when the internal buffer is empty.

My blog at https://sworthodoxy.blogspot.com/2024/01/ compares a Java solution of the Sleeping Barber problem with an Ada version of the Sleeping Barber problem. The explanations of both examples will hopefully help you better understand Ada.

I re-read the docs and it appears to me that Protected Objects are similar to Condition Variables because they provide a locking and waiting mechanism. A caller to an "Entry" may be blocked for a long time. But Triple Buffer is a Non-Blocking algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm ) and it guarantees that neither producer nor consumer can ever wait for each other or anything (other than memory access). Acquiring and releasing a buffer should take a constant time.

Ada protected objects are not at all like condition variables. Protected entries have boundary conditions, but there are also protected procedures with unconditional read-write access (and the read-write lock to go with it) as well as protected functions with read-only access and a shared read lock.

I am afraid we do not understand each other. When you say "protected", I understand there is exclusivity, AKA mutex. So that if one thread is executing "protected procedure", other threads will have to wait before executing a "protected procedure" on the same object. Is it true? If yes, if any threads can be forced to wait for any time, then it is not acceptable.
